# how is ruby global path variable set up?

Tags: ruby

If I do `ruby -v` I get:

```
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
```

But if I do `ruby -e 'puts $:'` I get:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:31:in `require': cannot load such file -- rbconfig (LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

What do I need to do to edit the $: variable so it stop looking for ruby 1.9.1?

Comment: Are you using rvm ( or pik if on Windows ) to manage your ruby versions? Try 'which ruby' to get the location of the ruby. Also do 'rvm list' and see all rubies installed. Then we can discuss.

Comment: That's about ruby install rather than `$:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$:` is the shorthand name for `$LOAD_PATH`.

Maybe `gem` is using a different Ruby than `ruby`; try:

```
which ruby
gem env | grep 'RUBY EXECUTABLE'
```

If you get different results, then we know where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks, the gem env thing led me to find the root of the problem. I had to rearrange the order of my PATH